# Trying to access CGAL Polyhedron vertex

Tags: c++, cgal

I wish to access the x,y,z values of a CGAL polyhedron Vertex.

The nearest code I have found is this

```
// polyhedron_prog_tetra.C
// -----------------------------------------------------------
#include <CGAL/Cartesian.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <CGAL/Halfedge_data_structure_polyhedron_default_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_default_traits_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>

typedef CGAL::Cartesian<double>                               R;
typedef CGAL::Halfedge_data_structure_polyhedron_default_3<R> HDS;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_default_traits_3<R>                  Traits;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Traits,HDS>                        Polyhedron;
typedef Polyhedron::Point                                     Point;
typedef Polyhedron::Vertex_iterator                           Vertex_iterator;

int main() {
    Point p( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    Point q( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    Point r( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    Point s( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

 Polyhedron P;
 P.make_tetrahedron( p, q, r, s);
 CGAL::set_ascii_mode( std::cout);
 Vertex_iterator begin = P.vertices_begin();
 for ( ; begin != P.vertices_end(); ++begin)
     std::cout << "(" << begin->point() << ") ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
 return 0;
 }

But when I try and compile I get a errors
/usr/lib/freecad/Mod/OpenSCAD/CGAL/CallCGAL.cpp:60: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/freecad/Mod/OpenSCAD/CGAL/CallCGAL.cpp:61: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
/usr/lib/freecad/Mod/OpenSCAD/CGAL/CallCGAL.cpp:62: error: ‘Traits’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/freecad/Mod/OpenSCAD/CGAL/CallCGAL.cpp:62: error: ‘HDS’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/freecad/Mod/OpenSCAD/CGAL/CallCGAL.cpp:62: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/lib/freecad/Mod/OpenSCAD/CGAL/CallCGAL.cpp:62: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/usr/lib/freecad/Mod/OpenSCAD/CGAL/CallCGAL.cpp:62: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
/usr/lib/freecad/Mod/OpenSCAD/CGAL/CallCGAL.cpp:63: error: ‘Polyhedron’ is not a class type
/usr/lib/freecad/Mod/OpenSCAD/CGAL/CallCGAL.cpp:63: error: ‘Polyhedron’ is not a class type
```

This system says I have to add some more comments, so here is some meaningless comments

Comment: `<CGAL/Halfedge_data_structure_polyhedron_default_3.h>` is not a header from CGAL. Where did you found the code you copy-pasted?

Answer (score 1):

Think the version I was trying from the internet was out of date. Found very similar but different code in the examples directory and this worked okay.

Comment: Please click on the tick next to you self-answer, to accept your answer, so that the question can be classified as "answered".

Answer (score 0):

Can you try these types:

```
typedef CGAL::Cartesian< double > Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Vector_3  Vector;
typedef Kernel::Point_3  Point;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3< Kernel > Polyhedron;
typedef Polyhedron::Vertex  Vertex;
typedef Polyhedron::Vertex_iterator  Vertex_iterator;
```